# if and else statement for id and class to change margin

Tags: javascript, html

I have try to fix my javascript / for (if statement) i trying to make if getElementsByid ('box')on href else change style for class ""bg to margin-top:10px

HTML code

```
<a href="#" id="box">click</a>

<div class="bg">Test</div>

<style>
.bg{
margin-top:100px; 
}
</style>
```

Script

```
function Element(id) { 
    if( document.getElementById('box') {
      document.getElementById('box').style.display = 'block';
    } else { 
      document.getElementsByClassName('bg').style.marginTop:'10px'; 
    }  }
```

Comment: are you calling this on click of div and anchor?

Comment: you are not calling the function

Comment: you are missing closing bracket for if condition

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName(cname) returns an array so you are not doing the right thing.

try

```
document.getElementsByClassName('bg')[index].style.marginTop
```

where index is the number

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="box">click</a>

<div class="bg">Test</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function element(id, index){
    if( index === null ){
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        document.getElementsByClassName(id)[index].style.marginTop = '10px';
    }
}

element('bg', 0);
```

**[Fiddle to answer here](http://jsfiddle.net/h_awk/aD4W9/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't comment posts, so I just want to notice to @Hawk 's post. 'bg' is not an ID, it's a class. so I guess the right way is

```
function element(id, elClass, index){
    if( index === null ){
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        document.getElementsByClassName(elClass)[index].style.marginTop = '10px';
    }
}

element('box', 'bg', 0);
```